# Trouble configuring Jenkins to email build results (using gmail)

Tags: android, email, jenkins

I have recently installed Jenkins on my development machine to help me learn how continuous integration/delivery works.

I have a basic Android task setup that will build my app and then report lint, PMD, Checkstyle, Findbugs, and JUnit (business logic) test results.

I would like Jenkins to send me an email with the build status (let's start simple and not require any additional information other than "hey the build is over, here's what happened: build failed/build succeeded" etc.).

I do not have my own email server/smtp server/etc so I would like to use Gmail if possible.

I've looked over a lot of documentation and other stackoverflow posts and I see that the following is the suggested approach in the E-mail Notification section:

```
SMTP server: smtp.gmail.com
Default user e-mail suffix: @gmail.com
Use SMTP Authentication: YES
User name: gmail address
Password: gmail address password
Use SSL: YES
SMTP Port: 465
Reply-To-Address: <empty>
Charset: UTF-8
```

Additionally, on my gmail account I've enabled less secure apps to connect to it or whatnot, that is enabled and I do not have two factor auth/etc. on.

When I test this configuration I get the following error though:

Failed to send out e-mail

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)

    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)

Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)

Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:507)

    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)

Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)

    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)

    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:581)

    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$5.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:248)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)

    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:138)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)

    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:92)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)

    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)

    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)

    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)

    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is SSL a must have requirement for your tinkering? Does it work if you turn SSL off?

Comment: @davehenry hello again :) SSL is a requirement AFAIK - all the guides/tutorials I've seen to setup Jenkins using Gmail have had the option enabled.  It does not work if I turn SSL off - I get a timeout error using the 465 port, and I'm not sure what other port I should use in this case.

Comment: hmmm, not sure I can help you then. I don't have permissions to view our Jenkins Mailer configuration to compare. fyi the non-SSL port is 25.

Comment: I appreciate the help, no worries.  I tried port 25 and I get a "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. n186sm607445qkd.23 - gsmtp" error now, so that won't work either.

Comment: I can't help but imagine this is due to me using Jenkins locally, and not from a server/third party box, etc - not sure how to fix this yet, but maybe someone has some thoughts?

Comment: @Zach i could successfully test your configuration with my own gmail-account. One difference: I am using app-password authentication, because i am using two-factor authentication. Maybe you could activate the non-less security authentication and generate an app password over this [webaddress](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) and try it again with the app password? Port 25 is only working with non SSL and you aren't able to send emails to other than gmail accounts.. Port 587 is for TLS. Maybe you could try this too? Does you have your jenkins running under https?

Comment: @ansib Thanks for the reply.  I turned on two-factor auth, generated an app password for Jenkins, used that as the password in Jenkins and I get the same result unfortunately (using port 25 and 587 with SSL on/off didn't work with various errors, so I'm not sure they should be used either).  My jenkins does not run under https - the address I'm using is: "http://localhost:8080"

Comment: @Zach i think the problem is the certification path, because your jenkins is running under http. You could try to import the google certificate into the JVM TrustStore or you start your jenkins under https (maybe with lets encrypt). For the import of the google certifacyte see [this post](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message). Under which OS is running your jenkins?

Comment: @ansib I am running Jenkins on Windows 7.  I tried installing the gmail (I did google.com too) certificate using the steps you provided, and as far as I know they are installed correctly, but now I get this error: "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target" ... any thoughts?

Comment: @ansib In fact it's the same error.  Doh! However.. if I change the jenkins arguments to use a hard set path for the cacerts file, i.e. "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_141\lib\security\cacerts" " then it works.  Before I was using "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="%BASE%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" " and it wasn't working, despite me being 100% sure I had updated the cacerts file in jenkins' JRE folder.  I guess that's not the java runetime being used though? Okay.  Anyways, it works now - how does the bounty work? Please make an answer and I'll assign you the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error of your logfile shows a wrong certification path. You have to import the certificate from gmail into the TrustStore of the Jenkins. See [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message) article, how to import it.

I am running Jenkins under a Linuxdistribution, so i am not sure, what exactly was your problem. I think you didn't use the right JAVA Path to import it in the first way. There is a file "jenkins.xml" in your installation folder, where everything is configured. Maybe there was something going wrong at the installation of the windows service or you change the used JVM to another one.

When you try to set the TrustStore to a absolute path, like in your comment  "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_141\lib\security\cacerts", you are going to be sure, that you use a store where the certificate is stored.

If you navigate to this page on the jenkins you get more informations, which Java version or java arguments you are using. http://localhost:8080/systemInfo

Comment: The article that was linked (https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message) helped me greatly - since I am using jenkins on a local instance there was a certificate issue that was messing up jenkins being able to send emails through gmail.  In order to make this work I did have to do a hard coded path to my java folder's cacerts file.  I'll look into this further when I have more time, but for now I am able to get this to work! As started, it's likely an environment issue/config issue for that part to work correctly.  Thanks again!